# Checkbox validation maximum not working

Tags: html

I'm trying to have multiple checkboxes and then a js script that checks no more than 3 are selected.
I've found codes online and all the comments suggest it works, but it doesnt work on my machine. There is no error, but nothing happens. 
Here's what I have in the header:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">


    function KeepCount() {

        var NewCount = 0

        if (document.form1.one.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }

        if (document.form1.two.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }

        if (document.form1.three.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }

        if (document.form1.four.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }

        if (document.form1.five.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }

        if (document.form1.six.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }

        if (document.form1.seven.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }

        if (document.form1.eight.checked)
        { NewCount = NewCount + 1 }


        if (NewCount == 3) {
            alert('Pick Just Two Please')
            document.form1; return false;
        }
    }
```

And then in my body I have form with the `id=form1` with these checkboxes:

```
     <label>
      <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="one" onClick="return KeepCount()"> One
  </label>
</div>

  <div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="two" onClick="return KeepCount()"> two
  </label>
</div>
```

..etc

Like I said, nothing happens. No error, but no js.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jquery with a lot less lines, see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m89k0u95/1/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 3");
    }
});
```

Comment: the fiddle worked, but not on my page :/ I copied it exactly

Comment: @user2903379 put this in your head section `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @user2903379 Do you have javascript disabled?

Comment: I'm guessing your checkboxes are in the DOM on initial page load?